# How do I store PDFs in Cassandra?

Tags: python, pdf, cassandra

I want to save some pdf files to Cassandra. I'm working on Cassandra in Python. Some answers suggested that I do it using BLOBs. But I'm not quite sure how to do it. The Datastax Documentation for BLOB talks only about data types like int and float. How do I do the same for files, specifically PDFs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285043/storing-pdf-files-as-blobs-in-cassandra-table

Comment: Yeah, I've checked it out, it was not of much help.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked and answered in [Is it possible to store PDF files in a CQL blob type in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72590962/).

While it is possible to store binary files in a CQL `blob` column, it's not a good idea to do so. For details, see my recommendation in the duplicate question. Cheers!